# How to use MySQL transactions properly

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, transactions

I need some help.

I have different files. For example:

- index.php, news.php
- include-scripts like: facebook.php, pay.php and more.

On all the pages (except news.php) a transaction is started at the beginning of the script, and ending at the end of the script.

On pages like index.php and news.php, I include pay.php. But the problem is: when I'm visiting index.php a transaction is already started, so now two transactions are active! But I can't remove the transaction-start from pay.php, because if I call the script from news.php there is no active transaction.

(My website is much more complex with many more pages and things).

Can someone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: You're going to need to explain a bit more clearly. What sort of transaction is this?

Comment: It's a MySQL transaction. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples

Comment: @jordy well stop :) ... you really should adopt one of the newer database engines... mysql extension is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to emulate nested transactions. To do this write a wrapper for your database access.(pseduocode)

```
class MyMysqli {
    protected $realDb;
    protected $transaction_count =0;

    public function __construct ($host, $username , $passwd, $dbname){
        $this->realDb = new Mysqli($host, $username, $passwd, $dbname);
    }
    public function __get($property){
        return $this->realDb->$property;
    }

    public function __set($property, $value){
        return $this->realDb->$property = $value;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args){
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->realDb, $method), $args);
    }

    // overload begin_transaction, commit and rollback
    public function begin_transaction(){
         $this->transaction_count++;
         if ($this->transaction_count == 1){
               $this->realDb->begin_transaction();
         }
    }
    public function commit(){
         $this->transaction_count--;
         if($this->transaction_count == 0){
              $this->realDb->commit();
         }
    }

    public function rollback(){
         throw new Exception("Error");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very good with OOP, but how to start a transaction? And can I make MySQL of this? (in a further stage I update my whole website to MySQLi / PDO)

Comment: now would be a good time to upgrade. but the concept is to only to start a transaction the first time and increment a variable, on commit decrement the variable and if it's 0 then to the commit.

Comment: for your googling search for 'emulate nested transactions in mysql`